# How to include JavaFX scene functions into public static void main

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point, scene

I would like to know if is there a possibility to include JavaFX scene functions into

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    …
}
```

Inside `public static void main` there is `launch(args)`;
a `helloworld.java` JavaFX program looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import static javafx.geometry.HPos.RIGHT;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));


        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        scenetitle.setId("welcome-text");
     //   scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label pw = new Label("Password:");
        grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

        PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

        Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 0, 6);
        grid.setColumnSpan(actiontarget, 2);
        grid.setHalignment(actiontarget, RIGHT);
        actiontarget.setId("actiontarget");

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
               // actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
                actiontarget.setId("actiontarget");
                actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(
            Login.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I would like to use all the whole program inside `static void main`, just like java Swing, just like the following program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class combotable {
static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
static JButton boton_nuevo=new JButton("nuevo");

public static void main(String[] args){


frame.setSize(400,400);


String[] petStrings={"Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig"};
//JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(petStrings);

JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(petStrings);
combo.setSelectedIndex(4);
//comboBox.setSelectedIndex(4);

frame.add(combo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

frame.add (boton_nuevo);

boton_nuevo.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
         String s = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
          if (s == "Bird")
                         {
                       System.out.println("Se selecciono Bird");
                          }

           if (s== "Cat")
                         {
                       System.out.println("Se selecciono Cat");
                          }
            if (s== "Dog")
                         {
                       System.out.println("Se selecciono Dog");
                          }

            if (s== "Rabbit")
                         {
                       System.out.println("Se selecciono Rabbit");
                          }
               if (s== "Pig")
                         {
                       System.out.println("Se selecciono Pig");
                          }
         }

}
);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Is there any chance to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your Swing example is incorrectly synchronized in that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Your JavaFX [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) is correctly synchronized in that "modification of scene graph operations to live objects (those objects already attached to a scene) must be done on the [JavaFX application thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)." You can override `init()` to do other initialization or to  construct JavaFX objects *other* than a `Scene` or a `Stage`.

Comment: You are welcome, but I'm curious about what you want to do in this context.

Comment: I have worked with Java programs with all my code inside public static void main (String args[]) {
    …
} it is just a style of programming, now i plan to move to JavaFX and inside JavaFX there is only a public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}, i dont want to use launch(args) instead of all the whole program, but it seems that there is no other way to work with JavaFX

Comment: Same for Swing; absent using the correct thread, the program may later fail in a non-determinitic way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer back